# Logic gate whose truth is 1101

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Is there a way to find a logic gate or how to make a more complex gate / bit operator from a wanted truth table
I wish to have this truth table :

0 0 = 1

0 1 = 1

1 0 = 0

1 1 = 1

Comment: Logically, it is `NOT(a) OR b`, where `a` and `b`are the two input bits. But difficult to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: You need two gates. There isn't one that does this. You combine outputs of multiple gates to form more complex ones. What specific issues are you having with that?

Comment: Not homework im almost 33 haha. 
No reason behind this question beside curiosity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a formal way of doing this if you cannot see it from the table.
Write the `sum of products` expression for the table. 
If `0 0 = 1`, then  A'B' is in the expression. 
If `0 1 = 1`, then  A'B is in the expression. 
If `1 1 = 1`, then  AB is in the expression.

Then, F = A'B' + A'B + AB 
Now, simplify the expression:

```
F = A'B' + A'B + AB
F = A'(B'+B) + AB      Distribution Law
F = A'(1) + AB         Complement Law
F = A' + AB            Identity Law
F = A'(B + 1) + AB     Annulment Law
F = A'B + A' + AB      Distribution Law
F = (A' + A)B + A'     Distribution Law
F = (1)B + A'          Complement Law
F = B + A'             Identity Law
```

It is `not(A) or B`.

You have to use a `not` gate and an `or` gate.

### Alternative Solution

As pointed out in the comments, you can come up from the `negated` version of the function. 
If `1 0 = 0`, then F' = AB' 
Simply, F = `not(A and not(B))`. If you distribute the `not`, then it will correspond to the same boolean expression as above.

Thanks to the comments for pointing out the shorter way.

Comment: A simpler way to find it: it is `not (A and not(B))`.

Comment: Either ways, kudos for the great answer. solves a simple problem, but formally.

Comment: Thank. That was the kind of answer i was looking for. There had to be ways to generalize this problem.

Comment: If anyone ends up here and want to search for more about this : The generic subject is boolean algebra.

Answer (score 1):

The truth table gives exactly one possibility for 0. This is the same pattern as with the OR operator (also one possibility for 0), except that the first operand should then be flipped. So it follows that the first operand should be negated to get the desired result:

```
NOT(A) OR B
```

This is actually the [*implication* operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional): the expression is false when and only if the first operand is true and the second not:

```
A => B
```

If we represent an operator with the 4 outcome bits for operands 00, 01, 10, and 11, then this operator has code 1101 (read the output column from top to bottom). For all possible operations we have this:

| Output | Expression |
| --- | --- |
| 0000 | `FALSE` |
| 0001 | `A AND B` |
| 0010 | `A AND NOT(B)` |
| 0011 | `A` |
| 0100 | `NOT(A) AND B` |
| 0101 | `B` |
| 0110 | `A XOR B` |
| 0111 | `A OR B` |
| 1000 | `NOT(A OR B)` |
| 1001 | `A <=> B` |
| 1010 | `NOT B` |
| 1011 | `B => A` |
| 1100 | `NOT A` |
| 1101 | `A => B` |
| 1110 | `NOT(A AND B)` |
| 1111 | `TRUE` |

There are many alternative ways to write these expressions, but as a rule of thumb: if you need three 1-outputs, look for an `OR` operator where potentially one or both arguments need to be flipped. If you need one 1-output, do the same with an `AND` operator. If you have two 1-outputs, do the same with a `XOR` (or `<=>`) operator, unless it is a trivial case where one of the operands determines the result on its own.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer

Comment: You can only mark one answer as accepted ;-)

Comment: oh I see that... I liked both answer.
Keeping muhteva as answer as it pointed me toward the laws of boolean algebra, which was exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

if your input is X1 and X2 and you want to have a 1 as output, you can look at the combination which is easy to define: threre is only one 0 - and then invert it

- the case for output 0: x1 and (not (x2) )
- invert the solution (de Mogan): not (x1 and (not (x2) )) = not(x1) or x2

You need 1 x not and 1 x or
or you need 2 x not and 1 x and